WidgetKit watch complication not updating on timeline dates
I'm having an issue getting my widget to schedule updates with the timeline. My watch is in Developer mode so the normal budget should not apply along with the app being attached to the debugger. I have the following code that takes an input date, for example now + 2 hours. Then depending on that date, I want to trigger reloads of my widget at specific times in order to format it differently.
The issue I'm having is that it seems to ignore all the other entries other than the first and last one.
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
    
    if let widgetData = UserDefaults.getEncodedDefault(type: WidgetData.self, key: "widgetData") {
        entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: widgetData.startDate, timerEnd: widgetData.endDate)) // Update on timer start
        entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: widgetData.startDate), timerEnd: widgetData.endDate)) // Update at midnight day of
        entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -1, to: widgetData.endDate)!, timerEnd: widgetData.endDate)) // Update at last hour
        entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: widgetData.endDate, timerEnd: widgetData.startDate)) // Update on timer end to clear
    }

    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
}

func formatDateAsDayHourMinuteSecond(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d h:mma" // Format for Month, Day, and Time (12-hour format)
            formatter.amSymbol = "am" // Optional: Set AM symbol
            formatter.pmSymbol = "pm" // Optional: Set PM symbol
            return formatter.string(from: date)
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if entry.timerEnd > Date.now {
            if let timerSeconds = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: .now, to: entry.timerEnd).second {
                Text("\(timerSeconds)") // I would expect this to change on update, but it never does indicating the timeline is being ignored.
                if isLuminanceReduced {
                    Text(formatDateAsDayHourMinuteSecond(entry.timerEnd)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                } else {
                    // Greater than one day
                    if timerSeconds > 86400 {
                        Text(formatDateAsDayHourMinuteSecond(entry.timerEnd)).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    
                    // Greater than 1 hour and less than 1 day
                    if timerSeconds > 3600 && timerSeconds < 86400 {
                        // less than one day
                        Text(entry.timerEnd, style: .relative).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                    
                    // Less than one hour
                    if timerSeconds <= 3600 {
                        Text(entry.timerEnd, style: .timer)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        Image("ComplicationIcon").opacity(entry.timerEnd < Date.now ? 1 : 0.33)
    }
}

